# BDD with JBehave and Eclipse4

Tags: testing, eclipse-rcp, jbehave, e2e-testing

Im my team we do TDD and we'd like to "close the gap" by trying BDD too (we do scrum, we have User story, etc).

I've seen that BDD might help us then I'm trying it. I've seen a lot using JBehave with web-based application, seems that the interaction with the browsers is easy.

We have an Eclipse RCP based application (E4, specifically) composed of UI part and a "service" part with JFace Databinding "keeping" those in sync. 
Does anyone of you have experience on that?

more specifically:

1. how is JBehave integrated with Eclipse RCP application?
2. how do you test the UI part? we've used SWT bot test but is a pain ... trying to avoid.

thanks in advance

_ _Kasper